# Create Process with FS Virtualization Enabled

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, uac, createprocessasuser

With UAC disabled, I need to create a process with the same characteristics as the process created with UAC enabled - basically I'm emulating process creation with UAC enabled.

My only roadblock is virtualization.  The sample code below should create an instance of notedpad at medium IL with virtualization enabled.  In actuality, it creates an instance of notepad at medium IL with virtualization disabled.  I'm not entirely sure why the virtualization token is being ignored.  Any ideas?

```
BOOL bRet;
HANDLE hToken;
HANDLE hNewToken;

// Notepad is used as an example
WCHAR wszProcessName[MAX_PATH] =
L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe";

// Medium integrity SID
WCHAR wszIntegritySid[20] = L"S-1-16-8192";
PSID pIntegritySid = NULL;

DWORD EnableVirtualization = 1;
TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL TIL = {0};
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcInfo = {0};
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo = {0};
ULONG ExitCode = 0;

if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, &hToken))
{
   if (DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL,
      SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, &hNewToken))
   {
      if (ConvertStringSidToSid(wszIntegritySid, &pIntegritySid))
      {
         TIL.Label.Attributes = SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY;
         TIL.Label.Sid = pIntegritySid;

         // Set the process integrity level
         if (SetTokenInformation(hNewToken, TokenIntegrityLevel, &TIL,
            sizeof(TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL) + GetLengthSid(pIntegritySid)))
         {
            // Enable FS Virtualization
            if (SetTokenInformation(hNewToken, TokenVirtualizationEnabled,
               &EnableVirtualization, sizeof(EnableVirtualization)))
            {
               // Create the new process at Low integrity
               bRet = CreateProcessAsUser(hNewToken, NULL,
                  wszProcessName, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
                  0, NULL, NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcInfo);
            }
         }
         LocalFree(pIntegritySid);
      }
      CloseHandle(hNewToken);
   }
   CloseHandle(hToken);
}
```

Comment: Isn't virtualization a feature of UAC?  I don't think you can have virtualization without UAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was approaching this incorrectly - fs virtualization is not what I want.  To emulate UAC, as described above, its necessary to create a restricted token with the administrators group disabled and use that token to create the process.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this doesn't work, is that the `SetTokenInformation` call to turn on virtualisation is working on the primary token created for `CreateProcessAsUser`. What's needed is an access token for the actual process. This can be obtained by creating the process with the `CreationFlag` `CREATE_SUSPENDED`, and calling `OpenProcessToken` with the process handle from `ProcInfo`. Use `SetTokenInformation` on that token to enable virtualisation, and then `ResumeThread` to run the process.